# How do I push random images from an array onto a canvas using ctx.drawImage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, html5-canvas, drawimage

I want to have a canvas that randomly displays a different animal-head every time the window is refreshed. Thus, I am trying to push a random image from my head array onto my canvas. As you can see below, this is my array.

```
var heads = ['animals/dog.svg', 'animals/fish.svg', 'animals/monkey.svg'];`
```

And here is the draw image function that I want the array to randomly push an image to:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 60, 50);
```

Here is the entirety of my code for context:

```
var heads = ['animals/dog.svg', 'animals/fish.svg', 'animals/monkey.svg'];

function gethead() { 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*heads.length);
document.write('<img src="'+heads[number]+'" />');}

window.onload = function () {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'dog.svg';


  img.onload = function () {
      // CREATE CANVAS CONTEXT.
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 60, 50); 
      // DRAW THE IMAGE TO THE CANVAS.
   }
}
```

Can anyone explain how I can make this work?

Comment: img.src = heads[number]

Comment: get element's reference in onload function img=getElementByTagName('img') then dont set to src to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a img element and set src to heads[generatednumber] and append it to body.

```
 var img=document.createElement('img');
 img.src=heads[number];
 document.body.append(img);
```

Using the same variable `img` which has with reference to image,Write a function for onload callback

```
img.onload = function () { }
```

and in  drawImage
pass the variable holding the reference of image i.e `img`

```
document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0,0);
```

Try running this snippet

```js
var heads = ['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/04/08/03/baby-623417__340.jpg', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028__340.jpg', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/14/08/40/newborn-1328454__340.jpg']; 
window.onload = function () {
     let number = Math.floor(Math.random()*heads.length); 
     var img=document.createElement('img');
     img.src=heads[number];
     document.body.append(img);
      img.onload = function () {       document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0,0); 
      //remove the image after drawing
      img.style.display="none"
         
      }    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed everything.

Comment: Yes, I just up-voted and marked it as the answer. This was the first time I ever used stack overflow. Really appreciate it.